# How could I preview a php file on the browser from a remote server?

Tags: php, remote-access, remote-server

I have a remote server on '`somedomain.cloudapp.azure.com`' and I have a php file named  on that server.

I would like to preview the 'index.php' file on browser to see the output. I used to open the files and edited it through terminal, but now I want to see the output of the php file.

I know from localhost I just put on the browser URL `localhost` and it preview the index.php, how to do that for a file that is on remote server?

Comment: Likewise of course... but with the externally reachable domain name of the remote server instead of `localhost`

Comment: somedomain.cloudapp.azure.com/path/to/index.php but it does not work

Comment: Why do you add the path? A URL is a virtual location, the webserver maps it to its root folder (which is `/path/to`) - at least that's how it's usually done. There could be rules which translate `path/to` into something different, but let's start with the basics - the file is physically present in the specified location...

Comment: because the php file is not in the home directory of that server there are multiple users and folders for that server so I specified the folder that contains my website (Php files).

Comment: can you just access the url/domain where your index file is hosted ?

Comment: No, I log in to the server through terminal using `ssh -l username somedomain.cloudapp.azure.com`. I never tried to access the domain is I did not have any web files it all data files.

Answer (score -1):

You need multiple thing to see your result on the web page running on the own server ; like that web server such as engine nginx or apache , php-cli , if you using database you need phpMySql and there dependencies.

Comment: The server is remote and I want to test (preview ) the php pages from browsers that is installed on my laptop. How could I preview the php page on my browser  after I installed the apache on the server?

Comment: after that you need set an ip address to your apache web server and link that with php app routing system or directly php files.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a hypertext preprocessor .

The PHP binary executable resides on the "server" E.g. to function with other files served by the Apache HTTP server, also running on the server, or "server-side" (hence the term, "Server Side Scripting Language").

For your browser to render a PHP file as-- it is presumed-- the "pre-processed" HTML; the PHP code as processed by the PHP binary for rendering as HTML (on the server), it is necessary that the "stack" (HTTP server software, etc.) running on your server does in fact [have such a PHP binary configured](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php) to communicate with requests from Apache.